# Huge performance gain in Java data processing by not using branches/conditions

Tags: java, performance, optimization

Ran the following Java snippet which showed a big performance difference. Java 11.0.9.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.

With condition, like `c = (res[i][j] >= 64)? 1 : 0;`, I got
`time in ms: 1216`

With no condition, like `c = ((((res[i][j] - 64) & 0x80000000)>>31)+1);` I got
`time in ms: 438`

Questions:

1. why is there such a big difference in performance
2. Is `c = ((((res[i][j] - 64) & 0x80000000)>>31)+1);` the best option?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class FastCompare {
    static final int ITEMS = 1000000;
    static final int ATTRS = 1000;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        byte[][] res = new byte[ITEMS][ATTRS];
        int i;
        int j;
        for (i=0; i<ITEMS; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<ATTRS; j++) {
                res[i][j] = (byte)(i+j);
            }
        }
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long a = 1;
        int c;
        for (i = 0; i < ITEMS; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<ATTRS; j++) {
                c = (res[i][j] >= 64)? 1 : 0;
                //c = ((((res[i][j] - 64) & 0x80000000)>>31)+1);
                a += c;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("time in ms: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        System.out.println("a="+a);
    }
};
```

Comment: If your posted code is correct, you are executing half of the work needed for the 'shift' case (the computation of `b`) even though you don't use it for the 'conditional' case. i.e., your benchmark is skewed.

Comment: @aguest Thanks for pointing out the inconsistency. I made a change and now it's more apple-apple comparison.  The result still stands.

Comment: On my machine both versions take the exact same time. I'm using Java 11.0.6, Windows 10, i7-7700. Maybe it's something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/12323248) but that is just a random guess.

Comment: @akuzminykh, my Java version is 11.0.9.1.  Curious what the time it took on your CPU? I know the result will vary depending on the CPU type, just want to have an idea. Thanks.

Comment: @pktCoder Both ~ 450 ms. I have a tip for you: Write the same thing in C and post the same question but for C if you observe the same problem. The C people will know better what's going on. I'm not saying you won't get an answer here; it's just less likely.

Comment: Thanks @akuzminykh for the link and for the tip!  I am going study it carefully before posting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/513259

Comment: The `… & 0x80000000` in your expression is pointless, as you’re masking out bits that get shifted out anyway. But you can simplify the entire expression to `c = 63 - res[i][j] >>> 31;` anyway. It’s not surprising that eliminating conditionals can lead to higher performance (as long as the resulting expression is not too complicated).

Comment: But mind that the optimized variant does not evaluate to the same result as `(res[i][j] >= 64)? 1 : 0` for input values in the range `-2147483648` to `-2147483585`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh) for perfomance testing. Don't trust naive `currentTimeMillis()` measures.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same result as you (though I used System.nanotime() instead as that's more reliable). It's probably because branching can cause problems with modern processor pipelining. See
https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts.html